# Populate HTML textarea with data taken from the DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I propose my case studies:I am developing a table in ASP.NET in which the fields taken from the DB are displayed (in this case Nome, Cognome, Azienda, Provincia) I find myself managing three functions: add, delete and update.
The first two solved without problems, but I'm having problems with the update.To manage it I developed a function in the back end (subsequently called by an AJAX on the client side) that does nothing but use a SELECT query to select the row taken into consideration (based on the ID) and check if it is present on the DB through a reader. Once this was done I thought I would retrieve the values ​​of the fields of that row and insert them in the corresponding text areas.
I can't find a solution to complete the function. I tried with `name.InnerHTML` (regarding the name field) but it says the name field has no reference.

C# code:

```cs
        [WebMethod]
        public static void Popoladati(string ch)
        {
            int chiavInt = Convert.ToInt32(ch);
            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Elenco WHERE Id_Identificazione = @chiavInt";
            int i = 0;

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["coso"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
                {                 
                    SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("chiavInt" , chiavInt);
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                                       
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                    reader.Close();
               }
        }
```

AJAX request:

```
     function edit(chiav) {
     
        let param = { ch: chiav };

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "Update.aspx/Popoladati",
             data: JSON.stringify(param),
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             global: false,
             async: false,
             function(a) {
                 return a.d;
             }
         });

         window.location.href = "Update.aspx?Id_Identificazione=" + chiav;
     }
```

I do not know if I have been clear, in case let me know that I will try to explain myself better

Answer (score 0):

Well, you first should show how you displaying that table.

You can use gridview, listview, or a repeater. I HIGH recommend you use one of these for the display of data (since then you can with relative ease send the edited data back to the database).

So here is a example - I used listview. I dragged listview on the page. clicked on the listview, and used the builder to build the database query and connection.

I then delete the edit template, alternating template, and also delete the data source control that will be dropped on the page. (and REMOVE the data source setting in the list view control property sheet. I do this since this generates all the markup for me, and thus only takes less then 5 minutes of time.

so, now we have this mark up:

```
   <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="HotelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="City" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>
                <td><asp:CheckBox ID="Active" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                <tr runat="server" style="">
                    <th runat="server">FirstName</th>
                    <th runat="server">LastName</th>
                    <th runat="server">HotelName</th>
                    <th runat="server">City</th>
                    <th runat="server">Active</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />
```

Ok, not much markup. The code to fill this view? We have this:

```
private DataTable rstTable = new DataTable();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        LoadGrid();
        ViewState("MyTable") = rstTable;
    }
    else
        rstTable = ViewState("MyTable");
}

public void LoadGrid()
{
    string strSQL;

    strSQL = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City, Active from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName";

    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,
                               new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)))
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
        rstTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);

        ListView1.DataSource = rstTable;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}
}
```

Note careful how we have a class (form level) table variable - and we persist it in view state (you could also use session().

Ok, now, so far VERY VERY little code. When we run the above, we get this:

[image]

Ok, so now we need the code for the save button. The user can edit, change - in fact tab quite much around almost like a spreadsheet. To save the edits, then the user can hit the save button. The code for the save button is thus now this:

```
protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

// move values from list view back to table.

foreach (ListViewDataItem vRow in ListView1.Items)
{
    var OneRow = rstTable(vRow.DataItemIndex);
    OneRow("FirstName") = (TextBox)vRow.FindControl("FirstName").Text;
    OneRow("LastName") = (TextBox)vRow.FindControl("LastName").Text;
    OneRow("HotelName") = (TextBox)vRow.FindControl("HotelName").Text;
    OneRow("City") = (TextBox)vRow.FindControl("City").Text;
    OneRow("Active") = (CheckBox)vRow.FindControl("Active").Checked;
}

// now send table chagnes back to database

using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City, Active from tblHotels where ID = 0", new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3)))
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
    SqlCommandBuilder sqlBuild = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

    da.Update(rstTable);
}
}
```

So what we do is pull the changes back from the list view into the table, and then use a data adaptor "update" command to save all of the changes back to the database in ONE shot!

You can of course toss in say a un-do button - that would simply just call load grid again, and thus un-do any edits.

So, as this point, you really don't need ajax, and you don't actually need MUCH code at all.

Also  the above approach works equal well for a gridview, or  Repater control.

I tend to like the listview - it does generate more mark-up out of the box, but I just go on a quite delete markup party for the list view. I prefer the listview since you do NOT need to wrap each standard .net control inside of a "template control" over and over  - which I find a pain.

So the above concept?
You create a  data table. Pull the data you want to edit into that table. You then bind the table to the gridview/listview/repeater for display (and this allows editing).

to save?

You pull data back from the data repeating item to the table. And then use the data adaptor to update ALL changes in ONE shot - this is not only faster, less code, less hassle, but the data adaptor is smart, and for rows not changed, then no update sql is generated behind the scenes.

The total code we write? VERY little, and we thus now have a data editing system that allows you to edit such data - and it behaves darn near like a spreadsheet, and you can even tab around to move the cursor.

So, this approach not only saves world poverty in terms of the amount of code, but it also means that you can edit the whole grid, and save the whole grid in one simple operation.